# 2016 chevy malibu battery

Tags: battery, chevrolet, malibu

I have a 2016 chevy malibu i tried to start my car last tuesday it would not start light radio everything came on. got a jump it started 6 days later same issue it says in the dash service battery charging station. has anyone had this same issue and may know what it is?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure, but I would recommend taking it to a mechanic or an auto parts store and have the battery and alternator tested. If they both seem fine, then it's probably an issue with the battery ground strap. Good luck!